# Style = “display=none;” not working correctly in my project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed web page using JavaScript. There are error in get two check box selected and remove. then two **tr** in display, when I not selected check box. How I solve this?

check error in images

[image][image][image][image][image]

There are select 2 box and remove but display 3 image and select 3 check box and remove again then hidden **tr** filed, but I want hidden, when I remove selected filed.

2nd image must be like this

[image]

but mine,

[image]

```js
var arr = [];
var selectedVal = 0;


$("input[name='invoiceTotal']").change(function() {
  selectedVal = this.value;
  var granTotal = 5000;

  if (this.checked) {
    arr.push(this.value);
  } else {
    //alert(selectedVal);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
    hidenSelected(selectedVal);
  }
  var sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0);
  console.log("granTotal : " + granTotal);
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("sum : " + sum);
  console.log("selectedVal : " + selectedVal);

  if (sum == 0) {
    hidenUpload();
  } else if (sum <= granTotal) {
    chowSelected(selectedVal);
  } else {}
});

function chowSelected(j) {
  document.getElementById(j).style.display = '';
}

function hidenSelected(j) {
  alert(j);
  document.getElementById(j).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr style="display: ;">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2771.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2826.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>b</td>
    <td>$200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2087.5" style="display: none;">
    <td>c</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4314.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>d</td>
    <td>$400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5000.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>e</td>
    <td>$500</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2771.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2826.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2087.5">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="4314.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="5000.0">
```

Please answer this question quickly.

Comment: Shouldn't the second image show only the `a` row? It is very hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @MattMokary I edit code please check.

Comment: I thing you mean   respected table row open & hide with  input box check and uncheck

Comment: yep with one condition check code answer the qustion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else if (sum <= granTotal)` is the problem ,At the time of `c` uncheck sum is less then `5000` .so the condition was `chowSelected` runned. so i was applied with if condition checked only allowed to `chowSeleced` function

```js
var arr = [];
var selectedVal = 0;


$("input[name='invoiceTotal']").change(function() {
  selectedVal = this.value;
  var granTotal = 5000;

  if (this.checked) {
   
    arr.push(this.value);
  } else {
    //alert(selectedVal);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
    hidenSelected(selectedVal);
  }
  console.log(arr)
  var sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0);
  //console.log("granTotal : " + granTotal);
  //console.log(sum);
  //console.log("sum : " + sum);
  //console.log("selectedVal : " + selectedVal);
console.log(sum)
  if (sum == 0) {
    hidenUpload();
  } else if (sum <= granTotal) {
    if(this.checked){
    chowSelected(selectedVal);
      }
  } else {}
});

function chowSelected(j) {
  document.getElementById(j).style.display = '';
}

function hidenSelected(j) {
  document.getElementById(j).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr style="display: ;">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2771.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2826.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>b</td>
    <td>$200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2087.5" style="display: none;">
    <td>c</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4314.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>d</td>
    <td>$400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5000.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>e</td>
    <td>$500</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2771.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2826.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2087.5">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="4314.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="5000.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `chowSelected` from

```
  if (sum == 0) {
    //hidenUpload();
  } else if (sum <= granTotal) {
    //chowSelected(selectedVal);//Remove this line
  } else {}
```

Try following code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr style="display: ;">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2771.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2826.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>b</td>
    <td>$200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2087.5" style="display: none;">
    <td>c</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4314.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>d</td>
    <td>$400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5000.0" style="display: none;">
    <td>e</td>
    <td>$500</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2771.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2826.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="2087.5">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="4314.0">
<input type="checkbox" class="invot" name="invoiceTotal" value="5000.0">

    <script type="text/javascript">
var arr = [];
var selectedVal = 0;


$("input[name='invoiceTotal']").change(function() {
  selectedVal = this.value;
  var granTotal = 5000;

  if (this.checked) {
    arr.push(this.value);
    chowSelected(selectedVal);//Show if it is checked
  } else {
    //alert(selectedVal);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
    hidenSelected(selectedVal);//Hide if it is unchecked
  }
  var sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0);
  console.log("granTotal : " + granTotal);
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("sum : " + sum);
  console.log("selectedVal : " + selectedVal);

  if (sum == 0) {
    //hidenUpload();
  } else if (sum <= granTotal) {
    //chowSelected(selectedVal);//Remove this line
  } else {}
});

function chowSelected(j) {
  document.getElementById(j).style.display = 'table-row';
}

function hidenSelected(j) {
  alert(j);
  document.getElementById(j).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this help me father education. but I want **At the time of c uncheck sum is less then 5000**.